# Program is having Segmentation Fault

Tags: c

it runs fine but when I type ./a.out it keeps saying segmentation fault and ends the program. Im fairly new and would like some help. i would like to keep the two processes as there own functions and im just lost on what im doing wrong...

im suppose to fill a list up with random numbers from 0 - 101 and and print off the list using pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 20
void FillArray (int * , int);
void PrintArray (int * , int);


int main(void)
{
int *NumList[SIZE];

FillArray (*NumList, SIZE);
PrintArray (*NumList, SIZE);

return 0;
}

void FillArray (int *array, int size)
{
int a;
for(a=0;a<size;a++)
    {
    array[a] = (rand() % 101);
    }

}   

void PrintArray (int *array, int size)
{
int a;
for(a=0;a<size;a++)
    {
    printf("%d ", array[a]);
    }
}
```

Comment: An int and a pointer to an int are two different things.

Comment: what environment are you running your code in? have you tried using tools such as gdb to investigate specifically where in your code you're getting this error?

Comment: yes but c would recognize that and give me an error when trying to use the wrong one

Comment: `int *NumList[SIZE};` is an array of integer pointers, all of which have an unspecified value (they're uninitialized). `FillArray(*NumList, SIZE)` is passing the first of those pointers (which is *uninitialized*) to `FillArray` which attempts to access that pointer as a valid address. That equals segmentation fault.

Comment: i have not used or heard of gbd. sorry im relativly new to this

Comment: lurker thanks so much! i think i see what i did wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code a bit

```
int NumList[SIZE];
FillArray (NumList, SIZE);
PrintArray (NumList, SIZE);
```

By writing `int *NumList[SIZE]` you actually declaring an array of `int*` - pointers to `int`. Not what you wanted, right? Then you write `FillArray (*NumList, SIZE);`. It dereferences your array, the result is its first element which is of type `int*`, that element you are passing to function. And you try to assign a value to its elements. Hence SEG fault.

Comment: thank you so much! it works perfect now! youre a life saver